# How to do an automated SWOT analysis with Text Mining

Tags: text-mining

has somebody an idea/approach how to do text mining for a SWOT analysis? (e.g. sentiment analysis) I need to assign categories (Strengths, Weaknesses, Opportunities, Risks) to words in a document and then rank them.

Comment: Please, see this topic: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64701/how-to-create-a-score-for-a-swot-analysis-strengths-weaknesses-opportunities